# Are $\mathrm{arccot}(x)$ and $\arctan(1/x)$ the same function?

Tags: trigonometry

In my textbook it asks for me to:

Prove that there is no constant $C$ such that $\text{arccot}(x) - \text{arctan}(\frac{1}{x}) = C $ for all $x \ne 0$. Explain why this does not violate the zero-derivative theorem.

But I believe I have found such a $C$, i.e. $C =0$!
I even asked WolframAlpha (http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arccot%28x%29+-+arctan%281%2Fx%29) which corroborates my answer.

This question appears in Apostol's Calculus Volume I, Second Edition: Exersize 6.22-11b

Edit: Mathematica's definition of arccot is different from the one in my textbook. Apostol's arccot maps a real number into $(0, \pi)$ while Mathematica's maps a real number into $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ Here they are super-imposed: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%28-1%2F%281%2Bx%5E2%29%29+%2B+pi%2F2%3B+arccot

Comment: The inverse trig functions are multivalued and therefore not uniquely defined, unless a principle value is given, so please clarify how you are defining the two functions.

Comment: @Ethan Usually $\arctan$ denotes the determination which takes values in $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$, no? But you're right, this is not so clear for arccot.

Comment: Here: http://www.intmath.com/blog/which-is-the-correct-graph-of-arccot-x/6009 there are two definitions of arccot. Which one are you using?

Comment: Oh! I had assumed that mathematicians were in agreement. My textbook uses arccot = pi/2 - arctan, which is a different version than Mathematica's according to @julien's link. Thanks!

Comment: It seems that, at least as Wolfram is graphing it, the reflection about $y = x$ is used...(analytic?)...Even though Wolfram evaluates the difference as 0, and returns "true" to the equality of each expression, it nonetheless produces its indefinite integral as $x(\arccot(x) - \arctan(1/x)) + C, which makes little sense, to have done if the difference is zero: why not return just "C"?

Comment: @amWhy When graphing an inverse function, it is always the reflection about $y=x$ that is used, as you know of course. The question was about the range of arccot.

Comment: @julien Yes, I see that...didn't mean to complicate things.

Comment: @amWhy You don't complicate things. Wolfram does...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So we'll take your textbook's definition:
$$
\mbox{arccot}(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan(x).
$$

Then 
$$
\lim_{0^+} \mbox{arccot} (x)=\frac{\pi}{2}=\lim_{0^+} \arctan(1/x)
$$
while
$$
\lim_{0^-} \mbox{arccot} (x)=\frac{\pi}{2}=-\lim_{0^-} \arctan(1/x).
$$
Since its derivative is $0$ on $\mathbb{R}^*$,
$$
\mbox{arccot}(x)-\arctan(1/x)=0
$$
for all $x>0$ while
$$
\mbox{arccot}(x)-\arctan(1/x)=\pi
$$
for all $x<0$.

This does not contradict the zero-derivative theorem because the function is not defined at $0$, so its domain is not connected.

Comment: And actually, arctan(1/x) gives the alternative definition of arccot(x).

Answer (score 2):

This is not a rigorous proof, it is intuitive one.

Let $y = \arctan\left(\dfrac1x\right)$ then 
$$
\begin{align}
\tan(y) &= \frac1x\\ 
\frac1{\tan(y)} &= x\\
\cot(y) &= x\\ 
y &= \text{arccot}(x)\\ 
\arctan\left(\frac1x\right) &= \text{arccot}(x)\\
\arctan\left(\frac1x\right) - \text{arccot}(x)&=0.
\end{align}
$$

It holds for $x \neq 0, \ x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: [The graph of $y=\mathrm{arccot}(x)$ :](http://intmstat.com/blog/2011/04/arccotx.gif)  $\mathrm{arccot}(x)=\begin{cases}
\arctan \frac{1}{x}+\pi \quad (x>0)  \\ 
 \arctan \frac{1}{x}  \qquad \quad (x<0)
\end{cases}$

Comment: From $\cot(y)=x$ you cannot conclude $y=\text{arccot}(x)$ since $\cot$ is not one-to-one.  Similarly from $x^2=y$ you cannot conclude $x=\sqrt{y}$.