# Limit involving inverse tan function

Tags: calculus, limits-without-lhopital

I solved the following limit using L'Hospital's rule, but can't seem to solve it without using L'Hospital's.
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{e^{-1/x^2}-1}{2\arctan x-\pi}$$

I would like a hint as to how to get started.

I was also wondering how to approach inverse trigonometric functions in general when they appear in limits, since I didn't understand any solutions to this type of problem that I looked up.

Answer (score 5):

As $\arctan y+\operatorname{arccot} y=\dfrac\pi2$

Set  $1/x=h$ and use [Are $\mathrm{arccot}(x)$ and $\arctan(1/x)$ the same function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304399/are-mathrmarccotx-and-arctan1-x-the-same-function) to get

$$-1/2\cdot\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{e^{-h^2}-1}{\dfrac\pi2-\arctan 1/h}$$
$$=-1/2\cdot\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{e^{-h^2}-1}{\arctan h}$$

$$=1/2\cdot\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{e^{-h^2}-1}{-h^2}\cdot\lim_{h\to0^+}\dfrac h{\arctan h}\cdot\lim_{h\to0^+} h=?$$

Comment: I believe it's necessary to restrict to the $1$-sided limit as $h \to 0^+$.

Comment: \text{arccot} looks different from \operatorname{arccot}.  Observe: $a\text{arccot}b$ versus $a\operatorname{arccot}b$. (I edited accordingly.) ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Travis,  Yes, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304399/are-mathrmarccotx-and-arctan1-x-the-same-function. But as $x\to\infty, h\to0^+$

Answer (score 2):

You may observe that, as $x \to +\infty$, we have
$$
\frac{e^{-1/x^2}-1}{2\arctan x-\pi}=\frac{(1-1/x^2)-1+O(1/x^4)}{2(\pi/2-\arctan (1/x))-\pi}=\frac{-1/x^2+O(1/x^4)}{-1/x+O(1/x^2)}=1/x+O(1/x)\to 0
$$ where we have used, as $u \to 0$, the standard Taylor series expansions
$$
\begin{align}
e^u&=1+u+O(u^2)\\
\arctan u &=u+O(u^2).
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I am a high school student and have not been taught (at least in my country) about this 'O' thing you're using, so please explain otherwise.

Comment: It is a powerful tool... Another way to see this is, as $u \to 0$: $$ \frac{e^u-1}u = 1+\epsilon(u)$$ $$ \frac{\arctan u-u}u = \epsilon(u)$$ with $\epsilon(u) \to 0.$Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, but i don't understand this epsilon thing either. I probably should be visiting a dumber forum.