# integrate $\frac{\sqrt{\arctan\frac{1}{x}}}{1+x^2}$

Tags: integration

I was trying to solve $\int \frac{\sqrt{\arctan\frac{1}{x}}}{1+x^2} dx$. I think I have the first step right, which is $\int \sqrt{\arctan\frac{1}{x}} d(\arctan x) $, but I'm not sure how to proceed. I considered integration by parts, but it seems to make the new integrand too complicated. please help. Thanks.

Comment: Try $u=arctan(1/x)$.

Comment: Go to http://www.integral-calculator.com/ and type this in: ((arctan(1/x))^(1/2))/(1+x^2) . It shows the steps and the solution

Answer (score 2):

$$
u = \arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \rightarrow du = \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x^2}} \cdot \frac{-1}{x^2} dx = \frac{-1}{1+x^2} dx
$$
$$
\int \frac{\sqrt{\arctan\frac{1}{x}}}{1+x^2} dx = \int -\sqrt{u} du = -\frac{2}{3}u^{3/2} + C = -\frac{2}{3}\left(\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)^{3/2} + C
$$
So:
$$
\int \frac{\sqrt{\arctan\frac{1}{x}}}{1+x^2} dx = -\frac{2}{3}\left(\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)^{3/2} + C
$$

Answer (score 0):

Sunstitute $u/\tan^{-1}(1/x)$.  Thus $x=\cot(u), dx=-\csc^2(u) du$.  You should find the trigonometric functions cancel out and the integral is then easy.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Using [Are $\mathrm{arccot}(x)$ and $\arctan(1/x)$ the same function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304399/are-mathrmarccotx-and-arctan1-x-the-same-function), as $x>0,$
$$\arctan\dfrac1x=\text{arccot}x=\dfrac\pi2-\arctan x$$

Let $\arctan x=u$