# How does $ \frac{1}{x}\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan\frac{1}{x}\right)$ simplify to $\frac{1}{x} \arctan x $?

Tags: limits, trigonometry, trigonometric-series

Here is a solution I read when trying to solve a problem, and I can't figure out how it jumped in this step here:

> $$ \frac{1}{x}\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan\frac{1}{x}\right) = \frac{1}{x} \arctan x $$

This was related to a limit and integral problem where $x \to 0^+$. Please let me know if more information are needed and I will edit!

Comment: Use http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304399/are-mathrmarccotx-and-arctan1-x-the-same-function

Comment: With the usual convention that $\tan^{-1}x\in(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$ we have $\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{x}=\frac{\pi}{2}$ for $x>0$ and $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ for $x<0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean this holds for all $x>0$.

- The factor $\frac{1}{x}$ on both sides is not really helping, since for any $x\neq 0$ your statement is equivalent to
  $$
  \frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan \frac{1}{x} = \arctan x, \qquad x > 0 \tag{1}
  $$
- Now, rearrange the terms: (1) becomes equivalent to 
  $$
  \frac{\pi}{2} = \arctan \frac{1}{x} + \arctan x, \qquad x > 0 \tag{2}
  $$

which is a [known identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Inverse_trigonometric_functions).

---

*One way (maybe not the most elegant) to prove this last identity is to observe that the function $f\colon (0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = \arctan \frac{1}{x} + \arctan x$ is differentiable, and (using the derivative $\arctan' x = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$) that $f'(x) = 0$ for all $x>0$. So $f$ is constant, and since $$\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = \arctan 0 + \lim_{x\to\infty}\arctan x = \lim_{x\to\infty}\arctan x = \frac{\pi}{2}$$ you get the result.*

Comment: Thanks for replying. The step I posted was near the final solution, and the $ \frac{1}{x} $ was needed. The final answer given was this: $ \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\arctan x}{x} = 1 $. So I was trying to understand that step I posted in the question.

Comment: @user321070 I'm not saying the $1/x$ should not have been there in your proof (which I do not know); simply that to establish the equality you need, getting rid of it can be done safely, and helps.

Comment: Ah ok, I understand now. It was strange and out of blue since this identity you mentioned has never occurred in my study until now. Thanks for helping out!

Comment: You're welcome!