# Arccot series summation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, summation, trigonometric-series

Find the value of:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathrm{arccot}\left(2^{k+1}+\dfrac{1}{2^k}\right)$$

I think we need to use telescoping method, but I am not able to convert this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

See [Are $\mathrm{arccot}(x)$ and $\arctan(1/x)$ the same function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304399/are-mathrmarccotx-and-arctan1-x-the-same-function)

Can you use
$$\dfrac{2^k}{2^{2k+1}+1}=\dfrac{2^{k+1}-2^k}{1+2^k\cdot2^{k+1}}$$

to find  $$\arctan\dfrac{2^k}{2^{2k+1}+1}=\arctan(2^{k+1})-\arctan(2^k)$$

Answer (score 4):

You know $$\cot(a-b)=\dfrac{\cot a.\cot b+1}{\cot b-\cot a}$$so 
$$\mathrm{arccot}(\dfrac{x.y+1}{y-x})=\mathrm{arccot}(y)-\mathrm{arccot}(x)$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathrm{arccot}\left(2^{k+1}+\dfrac{1}{2^k}\right)=\\
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathrm{arccot}\left(\dfrac{2^{k+1}.2^{k}+1}{2^k}\right)=\\$$ 
you can rewrite $2^k$ as $2^{k+1}-2^k$ so you will have 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathrm{arccot}\left(\dfrac{2^{k+1}.2^{k}+1}{2^{k+1}-2^{k}}\right)=\\
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathrm{arccot}\left(2^{k}\right)-\mathrm{arccot}\left(2^{k+1}\right)=\\
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f(k)-f(k+1)=\\\mathrm{arccot}(2)-\mathrm{arccot}(\infty)=\\\mathrm{arccot}(2)-0$$