# What is the result of the following limit?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits

I've tried to solve this limit without success. Any good idea?

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} (x-1)\arctan (x)-\frac{\pi}{2}x$$

Comment: what is $\pi(x)$?

Comment: What is the function $\pi(x)$ ?

Comment: Is that $\pi(x)$ as in the [prime-counting function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function)?

Comment: Ah, it was just $\dfrac\pi2x$.

Comment: Writing error. Sorry. I just updated my question.

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304399/are-mathrmarccotx-and-arctan1-x-the-same-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by egreg, $\lim_{x\to\infty} \arctan(x)=\frac \pi 2$.

So, if you know L'Hopital's rule, you can rewrite your limit as

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{\arctan(x)-\frac{\pi}{2}}{\frac1x}\right)-\lim_{x\to\infty}\arctan(x)]$$

and apply L'Hopital's rule to the first limit.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\arctan x=\frac{\pi}{2}$, so what you need to compute is
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\Bigl(x\arctan x-\frac{\pi}{2}x\Bigr)
$$
Note that, for $x>0$,
$$
\arctan x+\arctan\frac{1}{x}=\frac{\pi}{2}
$$
Use this identity and substitute $t=1/x$.