# How do I get the arctan-addition-rule to work with a multiplication infront of one of the terms?

Tags: trigonometry, trigonometric-series

i need help with this. I think, I'm missing a simple rule here, but i don't get it:

$180^\circ = \arctan(10 \omega) + 2 \arctan(\omega)$

I know that $\omega$ will be $1.099$ but I don't get how.

Comment: If you can deal with $\arctan x+\arctan y$, then you can also deal with $\arctan x+\arctan y+\arctan y$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Think of it as "$\arctan 10\omega + (\arctan\omega +\arctan\omega)$" and deal with the part in parentheses first. Then do it again since it will then be of the form "$\arctan 10\omega + \arctan(\textrm{first result})$".

Answer (score 0):

We have $\arctan(10\omega)=2\left(90^\circ-\arctan\omega\right)=2\text{arccot}\omega$

Now using Principal values of [Inverse trigonometric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values),

$-\dfrac\pi2<\arctan(10\omega)<\dfrac\pi2\implies-\dfrac\pi4<\text{arccot}\omega<\dfrac\pi4$

But $0<\text{arccot}\omega<\pi\implies0<\text{arccot}\omega<\dfrac\pi4\iff\dfrac\pi4<\arctan x<\dfrac\pi2$

$\implies1<\omega<\infty\  \ \ \  (1)$

$\iff0<\dfrac1\omega<1\  \ \ \  (2)$

Using [Are $\mathrm{arccot}(x)$ and $\arctan(1/x)$ the same function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304399/are-mathrmarccotx-and-arctan1-x-the-same-function), $$\text{arccot}\omega=\arctan\dfrac1\omega$$

Using my answer here [Inverse trigonometric function identity doubt: $\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}y =-\pi+\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x+y}{1-xy}\right)$, when $x<0$, $y<0$, and $xy>1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1837410/inverse-trigonometric-function-identity-doubt-tan-1x-tan-1y-pi-tan)  by $(2)$

$$2\arctan\dfrac1\omega=\cdots=\arctan\dfrac{2\omega}{\omega^2-1}$$

So, we have $$10\omega=\dfrac{2\omega}{\omega^2-1}$$

Now we must honor $(1)$