# Reference Triangle Issue - Trig

Tags: trigonometry

Evaluate $\cos(2\cot^{-1}(32/49))$

What I did for this problem was:

- Turn $\cot$ into $\tan(49/32)$
- And I am not sure what I do with the $2*$

I tried multiplying $49$ by $2$ and plugging the values into a reference triangle.

After I had all three sides I just found the $\cos$ of the triangle and used that as the answer but it was incorrect. I also knew i couldn't use any of the double angle formulas because the two is in front of the identity.

**The cot is inverse**

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Rephrasing the problem you need to find $\cos 2x$ given $\cot x=\frac{32}{49}$. Now can you solve it?

Comment: @AbishankaSaha Ah yes! I can use the Double-Angle Formula. Thank you =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By a well-known formula you have
$$\sin\left(\cot^{-1}x\right)=\frac1{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$
And, of course, the double angle formula
$$\cos2x=1-2\sin^2x$$
Now your solution is straightforward
$$\begin{align}\cos\left(\cot^{-1}\frac{32}{49}\right)&=1-2\sin^2\left(\cot^{-1}\frac{32}{49}\right)\\[10pt] &=1-2\left(\frac1{\sqrt{1+\frac{32^2}{49^2}}}\right)^2\\[10pt] &=-\frac{1377}{3425}\end{align}$$

Comment: Instead of a "well known formual" $\sin\left(\cot^{-1}x\right)=\dfrac1{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$ I'd say $\cot = \dfrac{\text{adjacent}}{\text{opposite}} = \dfrac{32}{49},$ so $\sin = \dfrac{\text{opposite}}{\text{hypotenuse}} = \dfrac{49}{\sqrt{32^2 + 49^2}}.$

Answer (score 1):

Use [Are $\mathrm{arccot}(x)$ and $\arctan(1/x)$ the same function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304399/are-mathrmarccotx-and-arctan1-x-the-same-function)

Now if $\tan^{-1}x=y,\tan y=x$

$$\cos\left(2\tan^{-1}x\right)=\cos2y=\dfrac{1-\tan^2y}{1+\tan^2y}=?$$