# Express $2\tan^{-1}x$ in terms of $\sin^{-1}$ and $\cos^{-1}$

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

$$
2\tan^{-1}x=\begin{cases}\tan^{-1}\frac{2x}{1-x^2} &\mbox{ if $|x|<1$}\\
\pi+\tan^{-1}\frac{2x}{1-x^2} &\mbox{ if $|x|>1$}
\end{cases}
$$

Similarly,

> $$
> 2\tan^{-1}x=\begin{cases}\sin^{-1}\frac{2x}{1+x^2} &\mbox{ if $|x|\leq1$}\\
> \text{____________} &\mbox{ if $|x|>1$}
> \end{cases}
> $$

and

> $$
> 2\tan^{-1}x=\begin{cases}\cos^{-1}\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2} &\mbox{ if $x\geq0$}\\
> \text{____________} &\mbox{ if $x<0$}
> \end{cases}
> $$

How do I derive the missing cases ?

**My Attempt:**

Take $\tan^{-1}x=A\implies x=\tan A$ where $\frac{-\pi}{2}<A<\frac{\pi}{2}\implies -\pi<2A<\pi$.

**Case 1 :**

$$
\cos2A=\frac{1-\tan^2A}{1+\tan^2A}=\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}=\cos\Big(\cos^{-1}\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}\Big)\\
\implies \cos^{-1}\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}=2n\pi\pm2A=2n\pi\pm2\tan^{-1}x
$$
As $0\leq\cos^{-1}\leq\pi$,

If $0\leq2A\leq\pi$
$$
\cos^{-1}\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}=2A=2\tan^{-1}x
$$

If $-\pi<2A<0$
$$
\cos^{-1}\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}= \color{red}{\text{?}}
$$

**Case 2 :**

$$
\sin2A=\frac{2\tan A}{1+\tan^2A}=\frac{2x}{1+x^2}=\sin\Big(\sin^{-1}\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\Big)\\
\implies \sin^{-1}\frac{2x}{1+x^2}=n\pi+(-1)^n.2A=n\pi+(-1)^n.2\tan^{-1}x
$$
As $\frac{-\pi}{2}\leq\sin^{-1}\leq\frac{\pi}{2}$,

If $\frac{\pi}{2}\leq2A\leq{\pi}$
$$
\sin^{-1}\frac{2x}{1+x^2}= \color{red}{\text{?}}
$$

what value should $\cos^{-1}\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}$ and $\sin^{-1}\frac{2x}{1+x^2}$ take and how do I proceed further ?

**My Understanding:**

For,
$$
\tan2A=\tan\big(\tan^{-1}\frac{2x}{1-x^2}\big)\implies\tan^{-1}\frac{2x}{1-x^2}=n\pi+2A
$$
If $\frac{\pi}{2}<2A<{\pi}$ I would take
$$
\tan^{-1}\frac{2x}{1-x^2}=-\pi+2A=-\pi+2\tan^{-1}x
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $\arctan(-x)=-\arctan x,$

Set $x=-y$ with $x\ge0,$ in $$\arccos\dfrac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}=2\arctan x$$

to find $$\arccos\dfrac{1-(-y)^2}{1+(-y)^2}=2\arctan(-y)=?$$

In $$\arcsin\dfrac{2x}{1+x^2}=2\arctan x$$ with $x\le1$

set $x=\dfrac1y$ to find $$\arcsin\dfrac{2/y}{1+(/y)^2}=2\arctan(1/y)$$

Now use [Are $\mathrm{arccot}(x)$ and $\arctan(1/x)$ the same function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304399/are-mathrmarccotx-and-arctan1-x-the-same-function)

Comment: thanx. i think it is the easiest way to derive other cases. could u pls confirm $2\tan^{-1}x=\pi-\sin^{-1}\frac{2x}{1+x^2}$ when $|x|>1$ and $2\tan^{-1}x=-\cos^{-1}\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}$ when $x<0$

Comment: @ss1729, What if $x=-\sqrt3?$  Cosine is fine

Comment: thanks. it is $2\tan^{-1}x=\pi-\sin^{-1}\frac{2x}{1+x^2}$ for $|x|>1, x>0$ and $2\tan^{-1}x=-\pi-\sin^{-1}\frac{2x}{1+x^2}$ for $|x|>1, x<0$.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

If $A=\tan (\frac {x}{2}) $ then

$$\cos (x)=\frac {1-A^2}{1+A^2} $$
and
$$\sin (x)=\frac {2A}{1+A^2} $$

Comment: thnx. but i knw that, mentioned in the post. thats not my doubt!