# Find the value of $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left(4\arctan\left(e^{x}\right)-\pi\right)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

I need to find the value of $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left(4\arctan\left(e^{x}\right)-\pi\right)\mathrm dx$$
**I've tried** to show this is an odd function in order to show the answer is $0$, but I wasn't able to do that.

How can I prove this is an odd function?

Comment: $\arctan u+\arctan\dfrac1u=\dfrac π2$, so…

Comment: I think you need to show it is an odd function in order to show the answer zero. It can be shown by using the identity given in the comment above.

Comment: @DEEPBHOWMIK Yes I meant odd.

Comment: @Saad Thanks! that should do it. but is that a basic identity? because its pretty much the first time I see it

Comment: This is an identity. You can see why this is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2814436/what-is-arctanx-arctany-if-xy-1?noredirect=1).

Comment: @JoeBenz Yes, it is. It's quite intuitive with a right triangle drawn.

Comment: N.b. The integrand is $2 \operatorname{gd}(x)$, where $\operatorname{gd}$ is the **Gudermannian function** (which is odd): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gudermannian_function.

Comment: Directly from @TravisWillse comment let $x=tu$ so $\int_{-\pi}^\pi\int_0^x\frac1{\cosh t}\,dt\,dxx=\int_0^1\int_{-\pi}^\pi\frac x{\cosh ux}\,du\,dx=\int_0^10\,dx$ since $\cosh$ is even.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Why not write up that computation as an answer?

Comment: @JoeBenz: The identity $\arctan(x)+\arctan\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ only works for [positive $x$](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/9tih8e0pxt). See my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $f(x)=4\arctan\left(e^{x}\right)-\pi$. Then since $\arctan u + \arctan 1/u = \frac{\pi}{2} \ (*)$:

$$-f(-x) = -4 \arctan e^{-x} + \pi = -4\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan e^x\right) + \pi =4 \arctan e^x-\pi = f(x).$$

$(*)$ can be proved geometrically: $\arctan u$ is the angle with opposite side $u$ and adjacent side $1$, and $\arctan 1/u$ is the other acute angle in the right triangle. Their sum must thus be $\frac{\pi}{2}$. Alternatively, differentiate the left-hand side and show it is constant, then choose a convenient value for $u$ since any $u$ works, say $u=1$.

Comment: The identity $\arctan(x)+\arctan\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ only works for positive $x$. Since $\arctan(x)+\arctan\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)$ is undefined for $x=0$, the function [$f(x)=\arctan(x)+\arctan\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)$](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/9tih8e0pxt)only has to be constant on a connected interval. Of course, these considerations are tangential to the question because in this case we are given $x\in[0,\pi]$.

Answer (score 4):

Write the integral as
$$
I=\int_{-\pi}^{0}4\arctan(e^x)-\pi \, dx + \int_{0}^{\pi}4\arctan(e^x)-\pi \, dx \, .
$$
Upon making the substitution $u=-x$, we find that
\begin{align}
I &= -\int_{\pi}^{0}4\arctan(e^{-u})-\pi \, du + \int_{0}^{\pi}4\arctan(e^x)-\pi \, dx \\[5pt]
&= \int_{0}^{\pi}4\arctan(e^{-x})-\pi \, dx + \int_{0}^{\pi}4\arctan(e^x)-\pi \, dx \\[5pt]
&= \int_{0}^{\pi}4\left(\arctan(e^x)+\arctan(e^{-x})\right)-2\pi \, dx
\end{align}
Note that
$$
\arctan(u)+\arctan\left(\frac{1}{u}\right)=\begin{cases}\dfrac{\pi}{2} &\text{ if $u>0$}\\ -\dfrac{\pi}{2} &\text{ if $u<0$} \, .\end{cases}
$$
In this case, $x\in[0,\pi]$, so $u=e^x>0$ and $\arctan(u)+\arctan(1/u)=\pi/2$, meaning that the integrand is the zero function. Hence, $I=0$.

Answer (score 2):

The answer expands on my comment, which remarked that the integrand of the given integral is twice the [**Gudermannian function**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gudermannian_function), $\operatorname{gd}$, which appears most famously in the equation governing the Mercator projection in cartography.

Differentiating the integrand gives
$$\frac{d}{dx} \left[ 4 \arctan (e^x) - \pi \right] = 4 \cdot \frac{1}{1 + (e^x)^2} \cdot e^x = \frac{4}{e^x + e^{-x}} = 2 \operatorname{sech} x .$$ In particular, this derivative is even. Since evaluating the integrand at $x = 0$ gives $4 \arctan (e^0) - \pi = 0$ the integrand is odd; since the integral is taken over an interval symmetric around $0$, by symmetry
$$\int_{-a}^a \left[ 4 \arctan (e^x) - \pi \right]\,dx = 0$$ for any $a$: In particular, the occurrence of $\pi$ in the limits of the integral is something of a red herring.

Comment: +1 Gotta love an answer that brings up an obscure function like the Gudermannian.