# Tricky integral question

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Find the value of : $I=\int\limits_{-1}^1 \left[ \frac{d}{dx}( \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{1}{x} \right) \right]\ dx$

My approach: $I=\int_{-1}^{1}d(\tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{x})) =  (\tan^{-1}(1/x))^{1}_{-1} = \tan^{-1}(1)-\tan^{-1}(-1) = \frac{π}{4}-(-\frac{π}{4})=\frac{π}{2}$.

Solution given: 
$$\frac{d}{dx}(\tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{x})) = \frac{d}{dx}(\cot^{-1}(x)) = \frac{-1}{1+x^2}$$

$$\implies I= -(\tan^{-1}(x))^{1}_{-1} = -\frac{π}{2}$$

Why is my approach wrong?

Comment: I think its because of the discontinuity of the function $\frac{1}{x}$ at 0 they avoided it by setting $\tan^{-1}$ to $\cot^{-1}$.

Comment: Your approach is wrong(I believe) because you can't use the fundamental theorem of calculus when the function in the integrand is not continuous, in this particular case, $tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{x})$ is not continuous on $[-1,1]$

(At least  not obviously)

Comment: This is a nice question! As a dry run, graph $\tan^{-1} (1/x)$ over the intervals [$-1,0)$ and $(0,1]$. Then, take a look at the hypotheses that you need for the manipulation you did above to be legal. (Look up the FTC page on Wikipedia.).    If you need more help, let us know.

Comment: Follow up - I meant YOUR question is a nice question - I don't altogether approve of the question you were given.

Comment: If you take $F(x) = \tan^{-1}(1/x)$ as an antiderivative, then $I = F(1) - F(+0) + F(-0) - F(-1)$.

Comment: @Maxim - just to say: 1)  you are (of course!) absolutely right; 2) I made an equivalent (but wordier) observation  in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost a comment, rather than an answer, but as the comments above were almost answers, it seems fair.

To given another example, which might make clear what is going wrong:

Suppose $$ f(x) = \cases{-1, & x<0,\\
                          0, & x=0,\\ 
                          1, & 0 <x.}$$

Now, except at $x=0$, $f'(x) =0$. (The graph of $f$ consists basically of two lines of slope $0$.)

Suppose that the question were to evaluate 
$$I=  \int_{-1}^1{d\over dx}f(x) \,dx.$$

The 'FTC method' would give $I= f(1) - f(-1) = 1- (-1) = 2$.

On the other hand, as $f'(x) = 0$ (except at $x=0$!), one should certainly get (geometrically, say, or Riemann sums) that 
$$ \int_{-1}^1{d\over dx}f(x) \,dx \,= \int_{-1}^1 0\,dx = 0.$$
This is in fact the 'correct' answer.

This is analogous to the question you were given.

I think that one can object that the question used the expression, ${d\over dx} f(x)$, which is only defined 'almost everywhere.' In the framework of a calculus class and Riemann integration, $I$ should be treated as an improper integral - and the given answer [although 'correct'!] does not do so... If one treats the integral as an improper integral (i.e., break up the integral around $x=0$, and take limits), and use your 'FTC' method, one gets the correct answer.

Likewise, the given solution uses
$$\frac{d}{dx}(\tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{x})) = \frac{d}{dx}(\cot^{-1}(x)) = \frac{-1}{1+x^2}.$$
But that equality fails at $x=0$.

FWIW, there is a 'theory of integration' (Lebesgue) that handles 'almost everywhere,' and does not make a distinction between proper and improper integrals.

Answer (score 2):

Need to split the interval in $[-1,0];[0,1]$

Method $\#1:$

Use [Are $\mathrm{arccot}(x)$ and $\arctan(1/x)$ the same function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304399/are-mathrmarccotx-and-arctan1-x-the-same-function)

For $x>0,$

$\arctan\dfrac1x=$arccot$(x)=\dfrac\pi2-\arctan(x)$

For $x<0,$

$\arctan\dfrac1x=-\arctan\left(-\dfrac1x\right)=-$arccot$(-x)=-(\pi-$arccot$x)=-\pi+\dfrac\pi2-\arctan(x)$

Method$\#2:$

Alternatively using [Inverse trigonometric function identity doubt: $\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}y =-\pi+\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x+y}{1-xy}\right)$, when $x<0$, $y<0$, and $xy>1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1837410/inverse-trigonometric-function-identity-doubt-tan-1x-tan-1y-pi-tan)

$\arctan x+\arctan\dfrac1x=$sign$(x)\cdot\dfrac\pi2$

Answer (score 0):

Here we will address your integral:
\begin{equation}
 \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{d}{dx} \left[\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \right]\:dx
\end{equation}
Now:
\begin{equation}
 \frac{d}{dx} \left[\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \right] = \frac{1}{1 + \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^2} \cdot -\frac{1}{x^2} = -\frac{1}{1 + x^2}
\end{equation}
Thus your integral becomes:
\begin{align}
 \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{d}{dx} \left[\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \right]\:dx &= \int_{-1}^{1} -\frac{1}{1 + x^2}\:dx = -2\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1 + x^2}\:dx \nonumber \\
&= -2\left[\arctan(x) \right]_0^1 = -2 \cdot \frac{\pi}{4} = -\frac{\pi}{2}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

There is a much easier way of doing this, note that:
$$\int_{-1}^1\frac{d}{dx}\left[\arctan\left(\frac 1x\right)\right]dx=\int_{-1}^1d\left(\arctan\left(\frac 1x\right)\right)=\left[\arctan\left(\frac 1x\right)\right]_{-1}^1$$

Comment: That was exactly my approach, which is incorrect.

Comment: Probably due to the point $x=0$