# $\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} \frac{\cos(2x^{-\frac{1}{2}})-1}{\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan(3x)}$

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

I'm having difficulties with this limit. We haven't covered integrals, derivatives, or things such as L'Hopital's rule in our course yet. What is the correct process to go about this limit?

$$\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} \frac{\cos(2x^{-\frac{1}{2}})-1}{\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan(3x)}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that by $\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan(3x)=\arctan \frac1{3x}$ and standard limits

$$\frac{\cos(2x^-\frac{1}{2})-1}{\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan(3x)}=\frac{\cos(2x^-\frac{1}{2})-1}{4x^{-1}}\frac{\frac1{3x}}{\arctan \frac1{3x}}\cdot12\to -\frac12\cdot 1 \cdot12=-6$$

Comment: thank you! I'm afaid I don't understand the whole reasoning (it's me--I'm in need of lots of practice...)

why does $\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan(3x) = \arctan \frac{1}{3x}$ ?

also, I'm trying to see how you got to that factorization. If I'm not making silly mistakes, then $2x^-\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2x}}$ so how do I get from that to the factorization you wrote? Thank you and sorry if I'm asking obvious questions, I'm clearly a noob haha

Comment: @SamueleB. For the identity refer to [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Inverse_trigonometric_functions).

Comment: @SamueleB. For the factorization the rule is to factor out expression in such way we obtain standard limits. In this case, since we have $\cos t-1$ at the numerator, we start with $\frac{\cos t -1}{t^2}$ and so on.

Comment: thank you so much! So $\arctan(3x) + \arctan(\frac{1}{3x}) = \frac{\pi}{2} \Leftrightarrow \frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan(3x) = \arctan \frac{1}{3x}$ makes total sense. Didn't know about the identity.

Comment: @SamueleB. Note that it is true for $(3x)>0$. It is not so difficult to prove.

Comment: so I think I get it. The first fraction on the RHS makes total sense, although now that we've added $4x^-1$ something else needs to be added to keep it equivalent. $\frac{1}{3x}$  now gets added to the numerator of the second fraction so we get the standard limit of $-\frac{1}{2}$. But now we have multiplied all the expression by $\frac{1}{12x x^-1} = \frac{1}{12}$ which is why we finally multiply by $12$ and the equation is now verified. Correct?

Comment: Yes exactly! Well done.

Answer (score 0):

Set $\sqrt x=1/y$

and use [Are $\mathrm{arccot}(x)$ and $\arctan(1/x)$ the same function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304399/are-mathrmarccotx-and-arctan1-x-the-same-function)
 to find

$$\lim_{y\to0^+}\dfrac{\cos2y-1}{\arctan\dfrac{y^2}3}$$

$$=-\lim\dfrac{2\sin^2y}{\cdots}$$

$$=\cdots=-\dfrac2{\dfrac13}$$